Dark comedy - I remember only one scene
I've been trying to find this movie for many years already, saw it maybe ten years ago or so while watching TV with my brother. The scene I saw was two demons or other kind of monster-like creatures talking about some guy's life and the guy jumps of the window of an apartment building. He was fat and wearing pajama or something like it.
The dialogue was funny, kinda Woody Allenish. It's something like a dark comedy, probably. That's all I remember since my brother turned the channel and i was really frustrated.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

That sounds like the Millennium episode Somehow, Satan Got Behind me, (1998).

Four elderly men meet for coffee late at night. The fourth to arrive
  is hostile to the waiter, who secretly urinates in the man's coffee.
  The man, Abum (Dick Bakalyan), realizes this, and the group share a
  laugh over it, during which they are revealed to actually be demons.
...
Abum tells another story, which he believes shows that mankind no
  longer needs demonic temptation to be damned. Abum followed an
  everyman figure called Brock, watching his grindingly repetitive life.
  Brock visited a strip club often but without joy, which led Abum to
  believe he no longer took pleasure from sinning. One day, Abum added
  an additional irritation to Brock's life, posing as a traffic warden
  and giving him a ticket. This was enough to drive Brock to suicide.


That's it, man! You're genius! Watching it now and couldn't be happier.
